# Steam WebAPI AuthenticateUser

Tags: python, authentication, encryption, steam-web-api

How to auth user via https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserAuth/AuthenticateUser/v0001 api method?

For example, I will get steam public key data from https://steamcommunity.com/login/getrsakey/, do some encryption and then send this data to specified api url as POST.
But server returns '403 Forbidden' everytime.

My code example:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Cipher.PKCS1_v1_5 import PKCS115_Cipher
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes
import hashlib
import json
import requests

steamid = '<MY_STEAMID64>'
steampass = '<MY_STEAM_PASSWORD>'
loginkey = hashlib.md5(bytes(steampass, 'utf-8')).hexdigest()
blob32 = get_random_bytes(32)

getrsa_url = 'https://steamcommunity.com/login/getrsakey/'
getrsa_data = {'username': '<MY_STEAM_USERNAME>'}

getrsa_resp = requests.get(getrsa_url, params=getrsa_data)
response = json.loads(getrsa_resp.text)
if response.get('success'):
    steam_publickey_mod = response.get('publickey_mod')
    steam_publickey_mod = int(steam_publickey_mod, 16)
    steam_publickey_exp = response.get('publickey_exp')
    steam_publickey_exp = int(steam_publickey_exp, 16)
    steam_rsa_key = RSA.construct((steam_publickey_mod, steam_publickey_exp))
    steam_rsa = PKCS115_Cipher(steam_rsa_key)

if steam_rsa_key.can_encrypt():
    sessionkey = steam_rsa.encrypt(blob32)
    if type(sessionkey) is tuple:
        sessionkey = sessionkey[0]
    steam_aes = AES.new(blob32)
    encrypted_loginkey = steam_aes.encrypt(loginkey)

if all([steamid, sessionkey, encrypted_loginkey]):
    authenticate_user_url = (
        'https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserAuth/AuthenticateUser/v0001')
    authenticate_user_json = {
        'steamid': steamid,
        'sessionkey': sessionkey,
        'encrypted_loginkey': encrypted_loginkey,
    }


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import ipdb
    ipdb.set_trace()
    authenticate_user_resp = requests.post(url=authenticate_user_url,
                                           data=authenticate_user_json)
```

authenticate_user_resp.ok returns False

authenticate_user_resp.status_code returns 403

authenticate_user_resp.reason returns Forbidden

*Sorry for my bad English, please*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AuthenticateUser doesn't do what you think it does. It's used by the Steam client to get web session logon cookies for the user who is currently logged into the client. The loginkey that AuthenticateUser asks for comes from the CM (the server which the client connects to).

If you want to log a user into the websites, you need to use the HTTP endpoints to do so. Once you have the RSA key and have encrypted your password with that key, you can authenticate by POSTing to https://steamcommunity.com/login/dologin/ with these urlencoded parameters in the body:

- `captcha_text` - Empty string or the text of a CAPTCHA you've been prompted with
- `captchagid` - The GID of the CAPTCHA you've been prompted with, or -1 if you haven't been
- `emailauth` - The Steam Guard code sent to your email address, or empty string if not applicable
- `emailsteamid` - Empty string
- `loginfriendlyname` - Empty string
- `password` - Your password, encrypted with the RSA public key, and the resulting ciphertext in base64
- `remember_login` - `true` if you want to remember your login or `false` if not (the strings `true` and `false`)
- `rsatimestamp` - The timestamp that you got with the RSA key
- `twofactorcode` - The TOTP code you got from your mobile app, or empty string if not applicable
- `username` - Your account name

Comment: Oh, thank you! Can you tell me how to get cookies with AuthenticateUser if I currently authorized by requesting to https://steamcommunity.com/login/dologin/? (how to create correctly parameters needed by method)

Comment: Authenticating with dologin will get you cookies. You don't need to use AuthenticateUser.

Comment: And steamMachineAuth?

Comment: The response to dologin will set a steamMachineAuth cookie if you didn't provide one already (and you have Steam Guard enabled).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am concerned, you are not allowed to do this operation, hence the "403 forbidden"  So, you simply are not "authorized" to perform this with the credentials you have.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403

> A 403 response generally indicates one of two conditions:
>
> Authentication was provided, but the authenticated user is not
>   permitted to perform the requested operation. The operation is
>   forbidden to all users. For example, requests for a directory listing
>   return code 403 when directory listing has been disabled.

Comment: I must be authorized to call auth method? How? :) For example, if I call this via get, server return code 405, reason 'Method not allowed' and text 'This API must be called with HTTP POST request'

Comment: what api are you trying to use out of the 4 (ITFItems_440, ISteamUser, ISteamUserStats, ISteamNews) ?

Comment: ISteamUserAuth. This interface contains two methods.

Comment: You can see it with https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamWebAPIUtil/GetSupportedAPIList/v1